# How to set up a new TM with the specified JVM heap size by adding JVM parameters?

Tags: java, apache-flink

How can i set up a new TM with the specified JVM heap size by adding JVM parameters in Flink manager page?
I tried the [Jvm parameters](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/zh/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup/#jvm-parameters) (`bin/taskmanager.sh start -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m`) but not works.

I know another way is to set the `taskmanager.memory.process.size` in flink-conf.yaml, but this will apply for all TMs, which is not my expectation.
Any suggestion will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

update: `taskmanager.memory.process.size: 4096m`in flink-conf.yaml, but i want get 1 special TM with more size like 6144m

Comment: Have you tried setting the FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS environment variable? I think that should work.

Comment: hi David, thanks for your reply. sorry i am new for flink, and seems less posts talk about this. do you mean add this in the command? （not work as well, but maybe i input wrongly?)  1.bin/taskmanager.sh start FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m 2. bin/taskmanager.sh start FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_TM -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m any suggest again? thanks

Comment: Try something like this: `FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx3072m" bin/taskmanager.sh start`. This isn't a Flink thing, it's about the shell (e.g., bash). Read up on shell environment variables to learn more.

Comment: thanks a lot, David, it works well.  and thanks for your suggestion, indeed the shell skill is my weak one, will learn more...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, as in

```sh
FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx3072m" bin/taskmanager.sh start
```

Note that giving one task manager extra resources is only useful if you make other changes as well (such as increasing the number of slots for that task manager), since Flink's scheduler considers all task slots as interchangeable.

Also see the docs for [fine-grained resource management](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/), which relates to this topic.